# Cmder PowerShell ignores profiles

Tags: powershell, user-profiles, cmder

I have some aliases set in `Current User, Current Host` and `Current User, All Hosts`.
Starting PowerShell (i.e. outside of Cmder) loads those profiles and so aliases are available.
Starting PowerShell inside Cmder ignores those profiles.

Is there anyway to make Cmder PowerShell sessions to read either of those two profiles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue is that Cmder comes out of the box with the PowerShell tasks configured with the `-NoProfile` option.  You can fix this through the gui (this shows I've already removed it...):

[image]

Or you can do it directly in the ConEmu settings, found in `cmder\config\ConEmu.xml`:

[image]

Comment: This really ought to be the default setup.  Thank you for posting.

Comment: Still necessary in 2022

Answer (score 1):

Run for check (outside of cmder of course, from `Win+R`)

```
ConEmu.exe -basic -cmd PowerShell.exe
```

Comment: Yup, running ConEmu like that does load PowerShell profiles. I'm guessing this is a cmder issue.