# how to load my Profile with ConEmu?

Tags: powershell, git, conemu

I have ConEmu installed and followed the instructions on this site https://hodgkins.io/ultimate-powershell-prompt-and-git-setup#install-required-components

I can't figure out how to load my `$PROFILE` at the start of ConEmu?

I also wanted to colorize my directories so I copied this script from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joonro/Get-ChildItemColor/develop/Get-ChildItemColor.psm1 and added it to my `$PROFILE`

Comment: So, what is your problem? What is your `$PROFILE` and what did you try?

Comment: My profile is not loading when launching ConEmu.

Comment: ConEmu most likely starts with `PowerShell -NoProfile`. look at this answer for reference: http://superuser.com/questions/956182/cmder-powershell-ignores-profiles